# Flattening an array of objects into another array of objects using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, design-patterns, object

I've come up against this issue in multiple contexts and languages and I always been able to work around it but I'd like to finally figure out a proper pattern to handle this.  It comes from joining SQL tables.  Usually I would make two calls, one for items and one for comments but I know there's a way to get it all in one call and then flatten the result.

What I'd like to do is to take an array that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    itemId: 1,
    comments: {
      commentId: 1
    }
  },
  {
    itemId: 1,
    comments: {
      commentId: 2
    }
  },
  {
    itemId: 2,
    comments: {
      commentId: 3
    }
  }
]
```

And turn it into this:

```
[
  {
    itemId: 1,
    comments: [
      {
        commentId: 1
      },
      {
        commentId: 2
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    itemId: 2,
    comments: [
      {
        commentId: 3
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should work for you:

```
function combine(arr) {
    var newObj = {};

    // combine the comments
    for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (newObj[arr[i].itemId]) {
            newObj[arr[i].itemId].push(arr[i].comments);
        } else {
            newObj[arr[i].itemId] = [arr[i].comments];
        }
    }

    // make the list
    var keys = Object.keys(newObj);
    return keys.map(function(key){return {itemId: key, comments: newObj[key]} })
}
```

Comment: Note that the order of `Object.keys` is not well defined, and you might reorder the elements accidentally.

Comment: Also note `Object.keys` does not exist in IE and must be added (es5shim)

Comment: Also, since you're already using ES5, you might like `Array#map` for the last step. It's slightly more readable ;-)

Comment: I'm wondering if `itemId` is guaranteed to be numeric. Otherwise, if you are _very_ unlucky, you might get an item with the ID `hasOwnProperty`. I feel it's worth a mention ;-)

Comment: @JanDvorak that would bum me right out! Hey OP! Your id's are sane, right?!

Comment: we could also do a `keys.sort()` if we really want to :)

Comment: id will always be an integer, yes.

Comment: @Andbdrew your answer is correct for this question but my question is off from what I actually needed, I got mixed up typing it out, and I'm unsure if I should post another question or edit this one.  Essentially, my starting array is simply an array like so: [{itemId: 1, commentId: 1}, {itemId: 1, commentId: 2}] etc.  The result I'm looking for is still the same.  Your answer has me on the right track I feel but I still have not yet figured it out.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually I just tried your updated answer and it works just fine for what I want.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Also you can use `filter()`:

```
function combine(src) {
    var dict = {};
    return src.filter(function(item) {
        if (!dict[item.itemId]) {
            item.comments = [ item.comments ];
            dict[item.itemId] = item;
            return true;
        } else {
            dict[item.itemId].comments.push(item.comments);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```